# Taking screenshots of a page while its loading using Selenium WebDrivers

Tags: selenium, webdriver, performance-testing, webpage-screenshot

I have started using Selenium WebDrivers to automate some performance testing. I found out that we could take screenshots of a page after the page has completed loading using WebDrivers: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#taking-a-screenshot. However, I want to be able to take screenshots while the page is loading to analyze its loading time and pattern, much like what webpagetest does (http://www.webpagetest.org/). Is there an API that I could use to accomplish this task using WebDrivers?

I am using the FirefoxWebDriver and the Java client for the same. I appreciate help or tips.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since, I found out that the RemoteWebDriver's get calls are blocking and even the getScreenshot calls are blocking, I decided to run java.awt.Robot in a separate thread and capture screenshots while the WebDriver loads the page.

The only caveat is that the browser instance opened up by the WebDriver has to be in the front of the screen to take snapshots correctly. I am exploring if Robot can take snapshots on an Xvfb display, which would be just awesome and would work for my purposes.